# Page<Book> findByBookName(String name, Pageable pageable) is not working for next page?

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, intellij-idea, azure-cosmosdb

"Not the first page but Pageable is not a valid DocumentDbPageRequest, requestContinuation is required for non first page request"
`findAll(PageRequest.of(1,10))` and `findByBookName("Name", PageRequest.of(0,10))` are working but `findByBookName("Name", PageRequest.of(2,10))` does not seem to work?

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "not working" ? Does it throw any exception or it simply returns an empty array ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ?

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.core.query.CosmosPageRequest;
private List<User> findAllWithPageAndSize(int pageNum, int size) {

        final CosmosPageRequest pageRequest = new CosmosPageRequest(pageNum, size, null);
        Page<User> page = userRepository.findAll(pageRequest);
        List<User> pageContent = page.getContent();
//        while (page.hasNext()) {
//            Pageable nextPageable = page.nextPageable();
//            page = userRepository.findAll(nextPageable);
//            pageContent = page.getContent();
//        }
        return pageContent;
    }
```

I'm not sure but CosmosPageRequest contains 'requestContinuation' which is mentioned in your error.

```
public CosmosPageRequest(int page, int size, String requestContinuation) {
        super(page, size, Sort.unsorted());
        this.requestContinuation = requestContinuation;
    }
```